Vercel POST request returns 500 error when uploading image in React Native with Node.js backend
I'm working on a Node.js backend deployed on Vercel, and I'm trying to update user information, including uploading an image using Cloudinary. However, when I send a POST request with the image, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. The server logs show "Function Invocation Failed". The API works fine if no image is uploaded.
Here’s my handleUpdateUser function:
const handleUpdateUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, gender, role } = req.body;
    let userimage = "";

    try {
        // Check if all required fields are provided
        if (!name || !email || !password || !gender || !role) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                status: false,
                message: "All fields are required"
            });
        }

        // Check if the email exists in the database
        let result = await AuthModal.findOne({ email });
        if (!result) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                status: false,
                message: "Email does not exist in the database"
            });
        }

        // Prepare the object with new user data
        let newObj = {
            name,
            email,
            password,
            gender,
            role
        };

        // Handle image file attachment
        if (req.files) {
            const files = req.files.image;

            // Ensure the image file is provided
            if (!files) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    status: false,
                    message: "Image Key is required"
                });
            }

            // Check if tempFilePath exists before uploading
            if (files.tempFilePath !== null) {
                const uploadResult = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(files.tempFilePath);
                if (uploadResult) {
                    // Remove the temp file after successful upload
                    fs.unlinkSync(files.tempFilePath);
                    if (userimage === "") {
                        newObj.userimage = uploadResult.secure_url;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Update user data in the database
        let updateDB_Result = await AuthModal.updateOne(
            { email },
            { $set: newObj },
            { returnDocument: 'after' }
        );

        const { matchedCount } = updateDB_Result;
        if (matchedCount === 1) {
            return res.status(200).send({
                status: true,
                message: "Your changes have been successfully updated",
                data: newObj
            });
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).send({
            status: false,
            message: "An internal server error occurred"
        });
    }
};

I am using express-fileupload middleware to handle file uploads:
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const path = require('path');

app.use(fileUpload({
    useTempFiles: true,
    tempFileDir: path.join(__dirname, '../tmp/') // Temp directory for uploaded files
}));

Here's the error message:
POST /quiz/userIndividualDetail 200 1919.543 ms - 602
Uncaught Exception: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/var/task/tmp'
at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1391:3)
at checkAndMakeDir (/var/task/node_modules/express-fileupload/lib/utilities.js:155:38)
at module.exports (/var/task/node_modules/express-fileupload/lib/tempFileHandler.js:14:3)
at Multipart. (/var/task/node_modules/express-fileupload/lib/processMultipart.js:75:9)
at Multipart.emit (node:events:517:28)
at HeaderParser.cb (/var/task/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:358:14)
at HeaderParser.push (/var/task/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:162:20)
at SBMH.ssCb [as _cb] (/var/task/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:394:37)
at feed (/var/task/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:248:10)
at SBMH.push (/var/task/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:104:16) {
errno: -2,
syscall: 'mkdir',
code: 'ENOENT',
path: '/var/task/tmp'
}

Add some debug logs to see which line is throwing the error.

The error message I received in Vercel has been added. On localhost, everything works, but on vercel it gives an error

Try process.cwd() instead of __dirname
